# Get Assembly qualified name of enum member

Tags: c#, enums, fully-qualified-naming

I have enum

```
  namespace ConsoleTestApplication
  {
    public enum Cars
    {
        Audi,
        BMW,
        Ford
    }
  }
```

now I want to get fully qualified name of enum member

so the result will be

```
ConsoleTestApplication.Cars.Audi
```

something like

> Cars.Audi.GetType().FullName;

or

> Cars.Audi.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;

what I am looking for, but non of those actually does what I need.

The reason of why I need it, because I have two identical enums in different namespaces (don't blame me on bad design, this is how it should be in my project)
and in one part of my program I need to use member of this enum, but because I have same enums it's gonna complain on ambiguity between same enums in different namespaces. So in order to avoid it I have to provide fully qualified name, reason of why I can't do it manually because this is kind of auto generated files, so I need to specify it programmaticaly at compile time

Comment: How will you be using it once you have it?  Why find it in reverse?  Where will you ever have `Cars.Audi` that you don't also have `ConsoleTestApplication.Cars.Audi`?

Comment: @Stanislav I still don't understand what you want. Do you want a string, type, object, or what? You've been given a couple of ways to get the FQN already, so it must be something besides a string, but I can't tell what it is from your question. Please don't use the word "name" to describe what you're looking for. That says "string" to me. Explain what type you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need a string?  If so, you could just use an extension method like this:

```
public static string GetFullyQualifiedEnumName<T>(this T @this) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum");
    }
    var type = typeof(T);
    return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", type.Namespace, type.Name, Enum.GetName(type, @this));      
}
```

If you're just trying to reference an ambiguous enum, just use `MyNameSpace.MyEnum.MyValue`, which would disambiguate it from `MyOtherNameSpace.MyEnum.MyValue`.

Comment: Why doesn't just using the enum's namespace work?  Like `MyNameSpace.MyEnum.MyValue`?

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it with a concatenated result:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cars car = Cars.Audi;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", car.GetType().FullName, Enum.GetName(typeof(Cars), car));
    }
}

enum Cars { Audi, BMW, Ford }
```

Comment: yeah, I could, but I need this value not to print it but to use it. because I have two same enums in different namespaces and in order to not have ambiguity I need to provide fully qualified name

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you update your question with an example of how you will be using the full name?